# tagging windows around events within data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, counter

I have a data.frame with a factor identifying events

> `year event
>   1    0
>   2    0
>   3    0
>   4    0
>   5    0
>   6    0
>   7    0
>   8    0
>   9    1
>   10   0
>   11   0
>   12   0
>   13   0
>   14   0
>   15   0
>   16   0
>   17   1 
>   18   0
>   19   0
>   20   0`

And I would need a counter-type identifying a given window around the events. The result should look like this (for a window that is, for example, 3 periods around the event):

> `year event window
>   1    0
>
>   2    0
>
>   3    0
>
>   4    0
>
>   5    0
>
>   6    0      -3
>   7    0      -2
>   8    0      -1
>   9    1      0
>   10   0      1
>   11   0      2
>   12   0      3
>   13   0
>
>   14   0      -3
>   15   0      -2
>   16   0      -1
>   17   1      0
>   18   0      1
>   19   0      2
>   20   0      3`

Any guidance on how to implement this within a function would be appreciated. You can copy the data. frame, pasting the block above in "..." here:

`dt <- read.table( text="...", , header = TRUE )`

Comment: What is your rule if overlapping occurs?

Comment: I had contiguous events (many 1s following each other). I selected the first to be the point of event I preferred and run either the answer by Roland, or the solution as a comment to the answer, on the redefined event vector, verifying that the windows did not overlap (they fortunately did not!). I also had to account for events close to the start and the end of the series by putting some bounds in the assignment (solution in the comment to the answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there is no overlapping, you can use on of my favourite base functions, `filter`:

```
DF <- read.table(text="year event
                 1    0
                 2    0
                 3    0
                 4    0
                 5    0
                 6    0
                 7    0
                 8    0
                 9    1
                 10   0
                 11   0
                 12   0
                 13   0
                 14   0
                 15   0
                 16   0
                 17   1 
                 18   0
                 19   0
                 20   0", header=TRUE)

DF$window <- head(filter(c(rep(0, 3), DF$event, rep(0, 3)), 
                         filter=-3:3)[-(1:3)], -3)
DF$window[DF$window == 0 & DF$event==0] <- NA

#    year event window
# 1     1     0     NA
# 2     2     0     NA
# 3     3     0     NA
# 4     4     0     NA
# 5     5     0     NA
# 6     6     0     -3
# 7     7     0     -2
# 8     8     0     -1
# 9     9     1      0
# 10   10     0      1
# 11   11     0      2
# 12   12     0      3
# 13   13     0     NA
# 14   14     0     -3
# 15   15     0     -2
# 16   16     0     -1
# 17   17     1      0
# 18   18     0      1
# 19   19     0      2
# 20   20     0      3
```

Comment: The assumption of no overlaps is crucial, thanks. I alternatively tried with 'which', with limited success: for(i in -3:3) DF$window[which(DF$event==1)- i] <- -i, but so some strange reason, I need to run 2 loops, none over negative i values - strange not to be able to do it in one run from negative to positive.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake with loops. This also works when no overlaps: for(i in -3:3) DF$window[which(DF$event==1) + i] <- i. Thanks Roland!

Comment: @BobPap: If this answer works for you, you should [accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). You'll earn a [badge](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/10) if you do! You may also want to earn the **Informed** badge by [taking the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).